# regain formatting for a Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2.444444,3],[3,4,3]], columns=list('ABC'))
df
```

My output is something like:

```
      A      B  C
   0  1  2.444444  3
   1  3  4.000000  3
```

How do i achieve that the column names are align with the rest of the column, and are right-justified as in various tutorial as in e.g.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html ?
Im using Python 3.5 in Liclipse+Pydev

Comment: This looks fine on my machine but I'm using ipython so you could use that instead

Comment: My machine: Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Shows correct formatting.

Comment: Same here, Ubuntu Linux 14.04 and 16.04, checked both in Eclipse, Spyder (w and w/o ipython console) and PyCharm. Its just a visualization problem, I would't worry about it too much.

Comment: Could it be that your environment is not in fixed-width font and hence the spaces take up less real estate?

Comment: I spent an embarresing amount of time trying all the formatting/display scripts that follows with pandas while the reason was as Arvindpdmn hinted: The used of a non-fixed-width font. Write as an answer and ill accept